# Show that this operator is linear.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, operator-theory

Let $X$ be a real vector space. Suppose that $T:X\to X$ is *affine*, that is, for $x_1,..,x_n\in X$ and $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\ge0,$ we have that $\sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i=1$ is satisfied.

Show that the operator, $S:X\to X$ where $S(x)=T(x)-T(0)$ is linear.

I think this should be pretty easy, and I'm sure that I'm missing something minute. Here's what I have so far.

Consider,

$$S(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_2)=T(\alpha_1x_1+\alpha_2x_s)-T(0)$$

$$=\alpha_1Tx_1+\alpha_2Tx_2-T(0)$$

$$=(\alpha_1Tx_1-T(0))+\alpha_2Tx_2$$

$$=\alpha_1Sx_1+\alpha_2Sx_2+T(0)$$

To move from the first to the second line we have used that $T$ is affine, and from the third to the fourth we have introduced a $T(0)$ to balance the reintroduction of the $S$ formulation.

The problem is that this factor of $T(0)$ brought in to balance the reformulation breaks the linearity that we are trying to show. What am I missing here?

Comment: Your definition for an affine map is incomplete. It does not depend on $T$.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean? What I stated above is the definition we have in the notes, which I see coincides with the "alternative definition" on the associated Wikipedia article. What am I missing which makes the definition I am using incomplete?

Comment: you have to use convex geometry because T is convex

Comment: In Wikipedia I don't see the $\alpha$-positive condition?

Comment: @JeremyJeffreyJames Again, look at that definition you have given, whether you have it in your notes or not. It doesn't seem to make any sense because it doesn't depend neither on $\;T\;$ nor on $\;x_1,...,x_n\;$ . What did you **really** try to say?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\alpha_1Tx_1 +\alpha_2Tx_2 - T(0) = \alpha_1(Tx_1 - T(0)) + \alpha_2(Tx_2 - T(0))$$
since $\sum\limits_{i=1}^2\alpha_i = 1$

but

$$\alpha_1(Tx_1 - T(0)) + \alpha_2(Tx_2 - T(0)) = \alpha_1Sx_1 + \alpha_2Sx_2$$